# Can CSS make an element appear twice?

Tags: html, css

Let's say you've got a long page. You've got your links in a `<nav>` that appears at the top. But as the reader scrolls down, it goes off the top. When they get to the end of the article, instead of making them scroll back to the top, you want to put the same `<nav>` content in the footer.

Without repeating yourself in the source, is there a way **in CSS** to make an element appear in more than one place like this?

(PS This is just an example so we have something concrete to refer to. I'm not particularly interested in usability/user experience arguments about this design; a more normal solution, of course, would be to make the `<nav>` stay on-screen while scrolling.)

Comment: The only thing that I could think of would be to know the scroll position, and when the "top" nav is not visible, adjust the `position` in CSS to be at the bottom of the page

Comment: CSS cannot. LSD probably could; but you might have little control over how often and when an element's duplicate appears.

Comment: Becomes time that CSS natively can detect scroll events like `body::scroll page 0 {}` and `body::scroll page > 1 {}` or something like that.. Then we could be able to position elements dynamic based on "pages".. We might be close CSS already supports [CSS Scroll Snap](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-scroll-snap-1/)

Comment: Could also be helpful if you want to display a big version from a visual list of small images (without the small version disappearing) and don't want to use javascript (to copy the src or similar).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arguments for User Experience and Accessibility aside - the answer is Yes. Sorta.

You can use `:after` and `position:absolute` to add css `content` to an anchor tag, then place it at the bottom of the page (`bottom: 0`). Browsers (as far as I've tested) will treat `position:absolute` `:after` content of an anchor as part of the anchor (meaning you can click on it, even if the original anchor hitbox is no-where near the `:after` `content`).

The gotcha here is: none of the parent elements can have `position:relative` or `position:absolute` on them. If they do, then the `:after` content will become absolutely fixed to the bottom of that parent element.

In terms of layout - the `:after` content will be inline with the end of the text of the original anchor. You need to use `transform:translateX` to shift the text to the left again. A value of `-100%` will shift the text fully to the left so the `:after` text appears directly under the original link.

This will ONLY work for a flat navigation style (no drop-down menus).

You will need to move the link text inside an attribute of the anchor (I've chosen the `title` tag) as something for the `content` to echo out. And because I don't like the same text inside an attribute AND in the HTML I've removed the text from the anchor.

```css
nav a:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(title);
  bottom:0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

nav a:before {
  content: attr(title);
}

body,
html {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#1" title="1"></a>
  <a href="#2" title="2"></a>
  <a href="#3" title="3"></a>
</nav>
```

Comment: great find.. you also might want using a padding-bottom in the body element so that the generated content will not be written on top of other content in the body

Comment: Also - this solution is not responsive friendly. If the nav links drops down to two lines, the after content won't. They'll start over-lapping each other.

Comment: Daft, hackish, ugly, completely unadvisable. It's perfect. +1 and accepted.

Answer (score 6):

No. Elements are the realm of HTML which creates the element in the DOM. CSS is presentation of those elements only and cannot create them and, no, `::before` et al is not the same thing. Yes, javascript can insert elements into the DOM but that's not the question.

Comment: That's about what I was expecting, but I'm so behind on what all the latest and greatest in CSS is, that I was honestly thinking there could be something like this now!

Comment: @TimPederick No, there isn't.

Comment: `::before` indeed it just places [display content you can't render html to a webpage](https://jsfiddle.net/cbk8hLm3/) with it..  Lucky for us otherwise it would a extra Cross side scripting vector to watch out for.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you may have a mis-understanding on what CSS does and what it is for.

CSS takes your HTML, makes it pretty, and shows it to the user. That's it.
That being said, CSS has taken major strides in the past few years, where we can now make animations, transitions, etc. However, these are still "making it pretty".

Once you enter the realm of "duplicating", it falls short. Only Javascript can modify a page like this, but most likely you are:

1. Not looking to use Javascript (for whatever reason)
2. Hoping you can do this simply

Well, there's good news. You can accomplish this without Javascript, and rather just use HTML/CSS to do it.

To do this, you'll need to have two `<nav>` elements. Luckily, most of the work of making it look nice will be taken care of by shared CSS classes.

Unfortunately, in order to keep them in sync without having to edit both `<nav>` elements when making a change, you'll need to utilize Javascript.

Comment: "I believe you may have a mis-understanding on what CSS does and what it is for." i don't think the topicstarter does. if you read his comment on Rob's answer. "That's about what I was expecting, but I'm so behind on what all the latest and greatest in CSS is, that I was honestly thinking there could be something like this now! "

Comment: I like to think I have a pretty good understanding of the role of CSS, if not of all its ever-expanding features. And given that it can make things appear 0 or 1 times, making them appear 2 times isn't beyond the bounds of reason. In fact it can already do that in specific cases (`background-repeat` comes to mind).

Comment: While your observations are completely correct, making things appear 0 or 1 times is not the way it really works. All it is doing is not displaying the element, which falls under the hood of "making it pretty". The element still exists in your DOM, so it's still there. `background-repeat` is always technically one element, and the repetition is handled by the styling. Again, nothing in the DOM is changed, which is what I am saying you cannot accomplish with CSS no matter what. Duplicating an element would mean to add a new, identical element to the DOM.

Comment: "the repetition is handled by the styling"--and that's what this question was about. You can justify a whole lot of stuff as being under the umbrella of presentation (or "making it pretty"). I remember years ago, when I *did* once have a very solid handle on most or all of CSS, people made your sort of arguments against `calc()`. But finally, some time around 2010...

Comment: It seems you ignored the rest of my comment. The DOM cannot be altered with CSS. What I've attempted to explain to you is that your requested use of CSS is not possible because it involves a change to the DOM structure. Anything that isn't manipulating the DOM can be put under the umbrella of presentation. `calc()` has nothing to do with this, because that implemented logic into CSS, still no changes to the DOM.

Comment: I read it, but within the constraints of 600 characters and the no-conversation-in-comments rule I didn't think I'd be able to argue the point properly. In brief, I disagree that *displaying* an element twice **requires** that it appear twice in the DOM. Hence no DOM manipulation, hence conceivably suitable for CSS.